# Override ArrayList and cast one to that class

Tags: java, arraylist, extends

I have an ArrayList as an Object(from reflection) and made my own class that extends off of it(ArrayListMonitor) that calls a function every time an arraylist has an item removed/added. But then I get this: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to ArrayListMonitor
I need to monitor the arraylist as I am loading a jar and creating a server from it, that has a clients field I need to monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ArrayList` is not of instance `ArrayListMonitor` this cannot work:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayListMonitor<String> am = (ArrayListMonitor<String>) a; // must throw ClassCastException
```

If you want to monitor the array list you have several options:

1. write a delegate like `new ArrayListMonitor(a);` and create delegates for all relevant methods in the `ArrayList`
2. Use a [dynamic proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to monitor ArrayList's behaviour
3. use other techniques like AOP

Comment: @Someguynamedpie: sorry, what you mean by 'detours'?

Comment: Detouring a function in the meaning of-- Redirecting calls of a function to another function.

Comment: Ok, got it. Yes, the proxy [intercepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern) certain method calls and you can decide if you want pass-through to your 'real' list or not. You can do things like logging, escalation, etc. The interceptor is fairly dynamic and complex, so the delegate my be the better option.

Comment: I love java 2000% more. Thank you so much for telling me about proxies, I'm going to pause this project and have fun with proxies now. It also solves problems I was having with sandboxing code.

Comment: Can dynamic proxies be used if the ArrayList object originates in some library code and is passed around down there? Don't we have to be in control of the creation of the life-cycle of the object to be able to use DynamicProxies?

Comment: It appears you misunderstood me, Proxies won't work as its the other program adding things to the arraylist.

Comment: @djna: Of course, we need control over the object, at least at a certain point in time to pass it back to the creator.

Comment: @Someguynamedpie: So you need to monitor an 'unknown' array list?

Comment: @home I asked because as far as I could see he did not have the control, otherwise he would not have had his original problem. If he had control he could have created his original hand-coded "proxy" object and not had the class cast problem. I don't think the problem is how best to create a proxy, it's how to instrument pre-existing classes.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you can't cast just any ArrayList to your ArrayList subclass.

As an analogy:

Every elephant is a mammal, but not every mammal is an elephant.
Every ArrayListMonitor is an ArrayList, but not every ArrayList is an ArrayListMonitor.

See the [Inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) section of the Java tutorial for more details.

---

And about your comment, have a look at this scenario:

```
OutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream("foo.txt");
OutputStream os2 = new DataOutputStream(os1);
DataOutputStream dos2 = (DataOutputStream) os2; // works
DataOutputStream dos1 = (DataOutputStream) os1; // will throw ClassCastException
```

Comment: I know that, but look at it this way.
An DataOutputStream extends OutputStream, and a outputstream can be casted to a DOS (afaik)

Comment: @Someguynamedpie that's exactly what I'm saying. No it can't unless it was actually created as a DataOutputStream. I'll add an example for that

Comment: @Someguynamedpie No, you cannot cast any arbitrary `OutputStream` to a `DataOutputStream`. That's exactly what Sean explains... Casting does not do any magic conversion. It just tells the compiler "I *know* this  object is really a `DataOutputStream`, so let me treat it as that". It does nog magically convert an arbitrary OS to a DOS.

Answer (score 0):

The object that you are trying to cast, what actual type is it?

```
 ArrayList anArrayList = new ArrayList();
```

or

```
 ArrayList aMonitorList = new ArrayListMonitor();
```

You will not be able to cast anything that is like anArrayList to your monitor list. You cannot add functionality to someone else's objects like this. You need them to use your special array class. Unless the code you are trying to instrument has some mechanism to let you say "use my class" then this approach will not work.

To be able to monitor pre-existing, compiled objects, it is technically possible to manipulate the compiled byte code, but that's a quite sophisticated technique.

Comment: `public class ArrayListMonitor<E> extends ArrayList<E> {`
is what im trying to say